# ZF2 domain specific object

Tags: php, zend-framework2

i have to fetch an entity object, based on the given domain of my application. Based on that entity, other services handle their requests.

Is there a way to store a static object or something like that? Or should i inject it into the other services, but where should i store it that way?

Thanks for any help

**-- EDIT --**

Now i have the following Service factory to return the wantend entity. But now i have the problem, that in case of the default domain, no entity exists and my application crashes because I can't return a null value in the factory. How can I solve that?

```
namespace Client\Factory;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class ClientFactory implements FactoryInterface {

    /**
     * @param \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return \Client\Entity\Client
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        /* @var $clientService \Client\Service\ClientServiceInterface */
        $clientService = $serviceLocator->get('Client\Service\Client');
        $baseUrl = $serviceLocator->get('Request')->getUri()->getHost();

        // client.mydomain.com returns a client entity
        // www.mydomain.com doesn't return a client entity
        return $clientService->getClientByBaseUrl($baseUrl);
    }

}
```

Comment: What did u tried so far?

Comment: Create your object by service manager - probably by factory. Create your other service by factories so you can grab your object and inject him to your services.